# How to change the SAPUI5 language?

Tags: internationalization, sapui5

I am searching for a way to change the language used in SAPUI5 "completely".
To change the language using a property file seems not to be a problem, a working example:

```
new sap.m.Switch({
    state : false,
    customTextOn : "EN",
    customTextOff : "DE",
    visible : true,
    change : [ function(oEvent) {
        var control = oEvent.getSource();
        var state = control.getState();
        if (state) {
            i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({bundleUrl:"i18n/i18n.properties", bundleLocale:"en"});
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
        } else {
            i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({bundleUrl:"i18n/i18n.properties", bundleLocale:"de"});
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
        }
    }, this ]
}),
```

Pressing the switch button will immediately change the text bound to "i18n>" model.
The problem is, that I also have text from metadata (especially lables) from the oData service.

A binding path could look like this:

```
{modelName>/#Entity/Attribute/@sap:label}
```

The language for this is defined during first logon. Now I am searching for a way to reload metadata (and also data) after a language change.

Is there any way to do so? Or is the only way to logout and login again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to reinit the `ODataModel`

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/your_odata_service",
                  {metadataUrlParams:{"sap-language":"de"}}
             );
```

This way it will retrieve the `OData` metadata for German via `$metadata?sap-language=de` again.

It just comes off the top of my mind. You can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I've had an issue to change the language that smartforms/smartfields are using for labels, as i couldn't control the language in which the labels were stated in the metadata.xml file. Allen solution worked for me! I am using the SAP Web IDE and i changed the manifest.json file adding this line were the principle or main (nameless, "") model is defined:

```
"models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "mpo.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "": {
            "dataSource": "mainService",
            "settings": {
                "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
                "metadataUrlParams": {
                    "sap-documentation": "heading",
                    "sap-language": "en"
                }
            },
```

Thanks Allen!

Answer (score 0):

Allen is almost right.

In order to reload the metadata file with the additional `sap-language` parameter, you need to destroy the model first and then `reinit` the new one. It is important, that you don't have any other `ODataModel` instance of the same service.

```
this.getModel().destroy();
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("/youService", {
    metadataUrlParams: {"sap-language":"de"}
});
```